# How to do a cascading IGrouping?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to do a cascading groupby, but I can't find a way to get the proper index in the end (the **.ElementAt(0)** in the end of the code is wrong, in all 3 levels of hierarchy).

```
        //Level
        //---|Category
        //---|---|Family
        //---|---|---|Type
        //---|---|---|---|Leaf

            var leafs = queryLeafs.ToList();

            foreach (var leaf in leafs)
            {
                //Get Type
                var leafAttr = leaf.ObjectsEav.First(eav => eav.Attribute.Name == "parent");
                long typeId = leafAttr.Value.Value;
                leaf.Type = universe.First(o => o.Id == typeId);

                //Family
                var typeAttr = leaf.Type.ObjectsEav.First(eav => eav.Attribute.Name == "parent");
                long familyId = typeAttr.Value.Value;

                leaf.Family = universe.First(o => o.Id == familyId);

                //Category
                var familyAttr = leaf.Family.ObjectsEav.First(eav => eav.Attribute.Name == "parent");
                long categoryId = familyAttr.Value.Value;
                leaf.Category = universe.First(o => o.Id == categoryId);

            }

            var groupType = leafs.GroupBy(leaf => leaf.Type);
            var groupFamily = groupType.GroupBy(t => **t.ElementAt(0)**.Family);
            var groupCategory = groupFamily.GroupBy(f => **f.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(0)**.Category);
```

Can someone provide a light in my dark path?
If you have any suggestion on how to improve this question, I would appreciate with all my heart.

Comment: Are you looking for `First()`?

Comment: No! But thanks anyway! I'm already trying something completely different. @NetMage